# Centralized MAC address database for Cisco switches

Tags: cisco, switch, security

I've seen this done before, but not sure how.

Looking for a way to have a centralized database of authorized MAC addresses and each switch to take the port-security status from this central database.  basically we want to put all allowed MAC addresses in a DB and then have each switch lookup the connected hardware before placing in the CAM table.

What does Cisco even call that technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of [802.1x](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3550/software/release/12.2_25_see/configuration/guide/sw8021x.html). You can use that to permit hosts based on MAC addresses.

This isn't the most secure way to authenticate hosts since [spoofing a MAC address](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/how-to-spoof-a-mac-address/) is fairly trivial and can be achieved with a single command, in most cases.

Comment: Man, I was really hoping to avoid 802.1X...

Comment: @ScottBoultinghouse I don't think there is a much better solution out there. From a security perspective, `Port-Security` just doesn't cut it anymore, despite it's continued widespread use.

Comment: dot1x is *not* what you want. *However*, it can be configured to fallback to MAC authentication which will get you where you want to be at the expense of a dot1x timeout.

Comment: @RickyBeam How is `802.1x` **not** sufficient for solving the OP? It does exactly what he needs done.

Comment: dot1x isn't what's doing it -- the *failure* of dot1x and it's subsequent fallback to "proxy" MAC authentication that works.  If the client is aware of dot1x and begins EAPOL, then it will most likely fail.  What he really wants is to have port-security authenticate on link -- much like a wireless system would.